# How to change font in webview for loadRequest

Tags: objective-c, fonts, uiwebview, ios8

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %@;", [UIFont fontWithName:centuryGothicBold size:5]];
    [self.longNewsWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:string];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a answer for my question  after long research

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
[self stopProgressHUD];
NSString *cssString = [[[[@"body { font-family:" stringByAppendingString:centuryGothicRegular] stringByAppendingString:@"; font-size:"] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",normalFont]] stringByAppendingString:@"}\""] ; //1

NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)"; // 2
NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, cssString]; // 3
NSLog(@"javascriptWithCSSString: \n %@", javascriptWithCSSString);
NSString *loadedContent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptWithCSSString];
NSLog(@"loaded ocntent: %@", loadedContent);
```

}

> centuryGothicRegular is the name of font which where declare as constant. 
>   normalFont is font size which is also declare as integer constant